# -preset veryslow not working with -vcodec copy using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am new to ffmpeg. I am using`ffmpeg` command to trim x265 mkv video and compress it as much as possible without losing quality. I am using `-preset` option with `veryslow` argument to make file smaller in size. I am also using `-vcode copy` and `-acodec copy` options with that.

Input file info:
Name: movie.mkv
Size: 4.42 GB
Length: 02:42:01

```
ffmpeg \

-i movie.mkv \

-ss 01:21:46 \

-t 00:05:27 \

-crf 0 \

-vcodec copy \

-acodec copy \

-preset veryslow \

song.mkv
```

The above command completing it's execution within a second and the size of `song.mkv` file is `150 MB`.

I don't think that it should complete the process within a single second with `-preset veryslow` argument. The `-preset veryslow` argument is suppose to take longer and make better compression?

Answer (score 0):

Stream copying causes decoding and encoding to be skipped - see https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy - so `preset` is ignored.

If you want to re-encode the clip to compress it, omit the copy commands and specify the encoding settings you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using `copy` on both `-acodec` and `-vcodec` is the opposite of compressing

You should use instead something like `-vcodec hevc` or `-vcodec h264`

You should also raise that CRF value, CRF 0 is also the opposite of compressing